# Lotus Notes application Document count and disk space

Tags: copy, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Using Lotus Notes 8.5.2 & made a backup of my mail application in order to preserve everything in a specific folder before deleting the contents of it from my main application.  The backup is a local copy, created by going to File --> Application --> New Copy.  Set the Server to Local, give it a title & file name that I am saving in a folder.  All of this works okay.

Once I have that, I go into the All Documents & delete everything out except the contents of the folder(s) I want this application to preserve.  When finished, I can select all and see approximately 800 documents.

However, there are a couple other things I have noticed also.  First - the Document Count (Right-click on the newly created application & go to Properties).  Select the "i" tab, and it has a Disk Space & Document count there.  However, that document count doesn't match what is shown when you open the application & go to All Documents.  That count is matches the 800 I had after deleting all but the contents I wanted to preserve.  Instead, the application says it has almost double that amount (1500+), with a fairly large file size.

I know about the Unread Document count, and in this particular application I checked the "Don't maintain unread marks" on the last property tab.  There is no red number in the application, but the document count nor the file size changed when that was selected.  Compacting the application makes no difference.

I'm concerned that although I've trimmed down what I want to preserve on this Lotus Notes application that there's a lot of excess baggage with it.  Also, since the document count appears to be inflated, I suspect that the file size is also.

How do you make a backup copy of a Lotus Notes application, then keep only what you want & have the Document Count and File Size reflect what you have actually preserved?  Would appreciate any help or advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question might really belong on ServerFault or SuperUser, because it's more of an admin or user question than a development question, but I can give you an answer from a developer angle...

Open your mailbox in Domino Designer, and look at the selection formula for $All view. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT @IsNotMember("A"; ExcludeFromView) & IsMailStationery != 1 & Form != "Group" & Form != "Person"
```

That should tell you first of all that indeed, "All Documents" doesn't *really* mean all documents.  If you take a closer look, you'll see that three types of documents are not included in All Documents.

- Stationery documents
- Person and Group documents (i.e., synchronized contacts)
- Any other docs that any IBM, 3rd party, or local developer has decided to mark with an "A" in the ExcludeFromView field. (I think that repeat calendar appointment info probably falls into this category.)

One or more of those things is accounting for the difference in your document count.

If you want, you can create a view with the inverse of that selection formula by reversing each comparison and changing the Ands to Ors:

```
SELECT @IsMember("A"; ExcludeFromView) | (IsMailStationery = 1) | ( Form = "Group" | Form = "Person")
```

Or for that matter, you can get the same result just taking the original formula and surrounding it with parens and prefixing it with a logical not.

Either way, that view should show you everything that's not in AllDocuments, and you can delete anything there that you don't want.

For a procedure that doesn't involve mucking around with Domino Designer, I would suggest making a local replica instead of a local copy, and using the selective replication option to replicate only documents from specific folders (Space Savers under More Options). But that answer belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser so if you have any questions about it please enter a new question there.